# Prove that the function $f:\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2}) \to \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})$ given by $f(a + b \sqrt{2})=a-b\sqrt{2} $ is an isomorphism.

Tags: abstract-algebra, functions

Prove that the function $f:\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2}) \to \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})$ given by $f(a + b \sqrt{2})=a-b\sqrt{2} $ is an isomorphism.

I need help with this one, mainly proving that f is surjective.

Comment: $f(a+(-b)\sqrt 2)=?$

Comment: The surjective part should not be the hardest part of the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: It's enough to see that there is an homomorphism $g:\Bbb Q(\sqrt2)\to \Bbb Q(\sqrt2)$ such that $f\circ g=g\circ f=\mathrm{id}$.

Comment: In fact, its sufficiently that $f$ is a ring homomorphism. Then, $f$ is necessarily injective since $\mathbb{Q}$ is a field, and is necessarily surjective since it will be $\mathbb{Q}$-linear and every injective endomorphism of a finite dimensional space is bijective.

Comment: @AlexYoucis Do you mean $g$?

Comment: No, I mean $f$. Any ring homomorphism will automatically be bijective by my above argument, and so already an isomorphism.

Comment: @PooperScooper If you liked this answer or any of the other answers provided by the other users then you can click the check mark beside the answer to "accept" it. If you have 15 rep or above, then you can even upvote an answer to show gratitude; you can upvote multiple answers. This will help the user and yourself.